# ORA-00907 "missing right parenthesis" extract month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

Having a horrible time with everything today. I am trying to get a list of month, year and then average the order total for each month. I am getting ORA-00907 "missing right parenthesis" and I am not sure why. Again, I very new to this, but the code that I have I referenced from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm .Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH, YEAR FROM ORDERDATE) "DATE"
AVG (ORDERDATE) "NO. OF ORDERS"
FROM ORDERINFO
GROUP BY EXTRACT (MONTH, YEAR FROM ORDERDATE)
ORDER BY "MONTH" ASC;
```

Comment: which one is your table orderdate or orderinfo there should be one

Comment: show us your tables and desired output

Answer (score 4):

The docs you referenced show that only one of the date part specifier can be of the extract function.

For example, `extract(month from orderdate)` or `extract(year from orderdate)`.

I'm guessing you really want to truncate the orderdate instead. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm.

```
SELECT trunc(orderdate, 'MONTH') AS "date"
```

Comment: Use TRUNC instead of TRUNCATE

Comment: Good catch @WernfriedDomscheit. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
select
  extract(month from orderdate) as year,
  extract(year from orderdate) as month,
  ...
from ...
group by extract(month from orderdate), extract(year from orderdate)
```

or:

```
select
  to_char(orderdate, 'YYYY-MM') as year_month,
  ...
from ...
group by to_char(orderdate, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```
select extract(month from orderdate) "MONTH",
       extract(year from orderdate) "YEAR",
from orderdate
group by extract(month from orderdate)
order by extract(month from orderdate) asc;
```

Comment: 1. What is the information your posts adds to the [answer Bohemian posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814036/754550). 2. Why do you think that the average of the month number is a meaningful number, especially why do you think it is the number of orders?

Comment: @miracle173 that is why i asked for tables and desired output